# illegalArgumentException:No positional parameters in query

Tags: hibernate

DaoLayer Code is:

```
String query="from hibernate.EmpRecord u where u.uname=? and u.upass=?";

          Query hql =session.createQuery(query);
          hql.setString(0, uname);
          hql.setString(1, upass);
                List<EmpRecord> userObjs= hql.list();
            if(userObjs.size() != 0) {
                    System.out.println(" User name : " + userObjs.get(0).getuname() + ", Status : " + userObjs.get(0).getIs_admin());
                    userStatus = true;

            }
            transaction.commit();
            System.out.println(userStatus);
    } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            transaction.rollback();
    }
    return userStatus;


}
```

Stack Trace is:

```
inside Process Method
Inside into service class
Inside into dao class
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No positional parameters in query: from hibernate.EmpRecord u where u.uname=? and u.upass=?
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.setString(AbstractQueryImpl.java:481)
    at hibernate.EmpDao.verifyUserDaoAndPassDao(EmpDao.java:32)
    at service.Empservice.verifyUserNameAndPassword(Empservice.java:20)
    at web.LogController.processCredentials(LogController.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Maybe try with spaces around the = in the query : u.uname = ? and u.upass = ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, tho my query and their parameters where syntactically correct. In my case, Hibernate threw this error because I forgot to add the mapping to hibernate.cfg.xml (or whatever kind of mapping config you are using) like that:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        ...
        <mapping resource="com/hibernate/myproject/MyClassMapping.hbm.xml" />
        ...
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

After adding the mapping, everything worked fine.

In this case, this is a very misleading error thrown by Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the count of placeholders and parameters help.

I faced this issue when I modified the query. Earlier my query had 2 parameters, after changes it had only 1 parameter and I forgot to remove a parameter from the parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error also,  Problem was that on my side.

There was a parameter waiting to be "set par = ?",  Normally position for first parameter is "0".

If you use 1 instead of "0" as position of parameter,  You will get this error.

So becareful about count of the parameters that waiting to be set.

in addition to that, i checked your codes. Here the problem is Mapping. You are saying that set parameter string, but In addition to that you are using Hibernate Query, not Hibernate SQL Query. In this case you should use Mapping. Because exception coming from **ANNOTATION.**