# nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No positional parameters in query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working in a school project where I work at backend with Java/Spring/Hibernate. While working with the database request, I got this error. I can't seem to resolve it. I tried starting parameter at 1 but it's the same error. 
Thanks for you help !

> Etat HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No positional parameters in query: FROM fr.netrust.model.User WHERE username=? AND password=?

model.User

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionIUD = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

        public User() {
            super();
        }

        public User(String username, String password) {
            super();
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return this.username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return this.password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

    }
```

UserDto

```
package fr.netrust.dto;

public class UserDto {

    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public UserDto() {

    }

    public UserDto(long id, String username, String password) {
        super();
        id = this.id;
        username = this.username;
        password = this.password;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

UserDaoImpl

```
package fr.netrust.dao.impl;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public int isValidUser(String username, String password) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query sql = session.createQuery("FROM fr.netrust.model.User WHERE username=? AND password=?");
        sql.setString(0, username);
        sql.setString(1, password);
        User result = (User) sql.uniqueResult();
        tx.commit();
        session.flush();
        session.close();
        return (int) (result==null?0:result.getId());
    }
```

UserController

```
package fr.netrust.web;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private UserDaoAdapter userDaoAdpter;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/log", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public int log(HttpServletRequest req) throws SQLException {
        return userDao.isValidUser(req.getParameter("username"), req.getParameter("password"));

    } 
}
```

datasource.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/NeTrust"></property>
        <property name="username" value="descartes" />
        <property name="password" value="descartes" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="fr.netrust.web" />       
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/pages/" p:suffix=".jsp"/>

</beans>
```

[EDIT]

```
@Override
@Transactional
public int isValidUser(String username, String password) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Query sql = session.createQuery("FROM fr.netrust.model.User U WHERE U.username = :username AND U.password = :password");
    sql.setParameter("username", username);
    sql.setParameter("password", password);
    User result = (User) sql.uniqueResult();
    tx.commit();
    session.flush();
    session.close();
    return (int) (result==null?0:result.getId());
}
```

Comment: Have you updated your [mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610221/illegalargumentexceptionno-positional-parameters-in-query)?

Comment: I don't have hibernate conf file. But my mate gave me a bean file with some hibernate configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The setString is 1 based index like in this example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

So

```
sql.setString(1, username);
sql.setString(2, password);
```

should works.

Edited: My bad it's hibernate.

First, use named parameters like in this example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm

with hibernate, you must use alias for your table. Hence the query must be something like:

```
Query sql = session.createQuery("FROM fr.netrust.model.User U" +
    " WHERE U.username=:username AND U.password=password");
sql.setString("username", username);
sql.setString("password", password);
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a 'SELECT like this: session.createQuery("SELECT * FROM ..."

Comment: I didn't but I just tried, and that doesn't change the output.

Comment: I'm so thankful for your help :). I tried to use what you edited and with the doc, but it I have another error : Etat HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [username]
I edited my post at the end so you can see my new code.

Comment: Probably use setParameter instead of setString

Comment: I did use setParameter instead of setString but that doesn't work. Well, it's a new error tho.